# If/Then python script in Field Calculator not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I'm working in Modelbuilder. I have a polygon in which I calculate the shape centroid in decimal coordinates (field called LONG_CENTR). Then I add a field (called FAJA) and I want to use a Field Calculator to assign it a value according to the centroid I've obtained previously. I think I have messed up the code in the field calculator.

Python-parser expression:

```
updateValue( !FAJA! )
```

Code Block:

```
def updateValue(FAJA) :
  if (70.500 <= match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) <= 73.500):
    return 1
  elif (67.500 <= math.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) < 70.500):
    return 2
  elif (64.500 <= math.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) < 67.500):       return 3
  elif (61.500 <= math.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) < 64.500):
     return 4
  elif (58.500 <= math.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) < 61.500):
    return 5
  elif (55.500 <= math.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) < 58.500):
    return 6
  elif (53.500 <= math.fabs(LONG_CENTR) and match.fabs(LONG_CENTR) < 55.500):
    return 7
  else:
    return 0
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: replace( -69.256 ) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in replace
NameError: global name 'match' is not defined

Failed to execute (Assign Faja Value).
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a repeated typo: match.fabs instead of math.fabs.  math is a python library, fabs is the absolute value function.

Comment: Thanks J Kelly. I fixed that and the expression and everything worked.

Comment: @inesingeniera If this answer worked for you, please consider voting and accepting.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)